# SSN and 9 digit number screening currently catching to many variables

Tags: regex

Here are the 2 regex's used.  The first is for a SSN type number with separators and the second is a straight 9-digit number with checks for characters before and after.

Regex("\D{1}\d{3}\D{1}\d{2}\D{1}\d{4}\D{1}")

Regex("\D{1}\d{9}\D{1}")

The problem is we catch other entries that resemble those but we need to be specific enough these aren't caught.

Such as -

(xxxx) xxx-xx-xxxx

684072943 (and order number etc.)

FA300217F0090

Potential Match #1:--------------- nt: ex: 201[[71230 0821]] am ex: 201[[71230 0821]] am 26 JUNE 2012 ---------------Potential Match #2:--------------- am ex: 201[[71230 0821]] am 26 JUNE 2012 DTG (date time group)

"[[ 210v13:2012]],"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Quite of bit of your premise isn't correct.  Do you want to match 9 digits or not?  Because 684072943  is nine digits. (xxxx) xxx-xx-xxxx is also gonna be the right SSN format,  but you say it's invalid because of something that preceded it, which is a bit of a stretch here (and difficult, if not impossible, to verify with regex).  FA300217F0090 doesn't match anything at all.  210v13:2012 might end up matching, but that can be addressed.

Maybe you should only consider 'SSN types' with the correct 3-2-4 format (delimited) in the first place.

You could [try](https://regex101.com/r/ITkM8a/1/), say:

```
\b\d{3}(\D)\d{2}\1\d{4}\b
```

We use word boundaries the edges of the pattern, and we back-reference the delimiter with `\1` so that they are guaranteed to be the same character.  I'm not sure if it's wise to allow ANY non-numeric delimiter, not just dash/space etc, but this will do that.

Lastly, I googled, and this topic appears to be [on the 'net already](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssn%20regex&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS707US707&oq=ssn%20regex&aqs=chrome..69i57.1231j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: FA300217F0090 doesn't match anything at all. 210v13:2012 might end up matching, but that can be addressed. How so?

Comment: "we back-reference the delimiter with \1 so that they are guaranteed to be the same character."

Comment: "I'm not sure if it's wise to allow ANY non-numeric delimiter, not just dash/space etc, but this will do that."  Whats the best way to limit it just to dashes and spaces?